# Is a full sign-in required to verify a phone number using Firebase Phone Auth?

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebaseui

A question about firebase auth for authentication via phone number.

I was wondering if it was possible to link a "Phone Provider" to say a Google Auth Provider. There is no explicit mention of it in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking).

The thing that had me scratching my head is - the Link Multiple Auth Provider docs talk about starting to authenticate with the new provider (phone provider) you want to link to the existing provider (google provider), but then stopping short of calling `FirebaseAuth.signInWithXXX`.

So in theory that would work like:

1. The user logs in via google (google idp provider)
2. The user kicks off the phone auth (phone number provider) - and gets an sms message.
3. The SMS should trigger an automatic verification in some cases or he types in the 6 digit code from the sms message
4. But based on the docs on account-linking, rather than call `FirebaseAuth.signInWithXXX` here, we can instead call `FirebaseUser.linkWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential)`.

So i was wondering if a phone number verification is considered complete without an explicit sign-in with the `PhoneAuthCredential` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can link a PhoneAuthCredential to an existing user, in your case, a user with a GoogleAuthProvider.

After you sign in the user with Google.
You then go through `PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, ...)`
This would resolve with a PhoneAuthCredential or a verification ID. You can then ask for the SMS code and instantiate a PhoneAuthCredential via `PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential`.

You can then link that credential to the currentUser: `currentUser.linkWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)`

Comment: Thanks bojeil! That indeed works. For some reason i convinced myself that phone verification is NOT complete until you sign in with the phone credential. But the very act of signing in with that phone credential, meant that a new user is created against the phone number and i can no longer link that phone credential to another existing user. So i am hoping that the linkWithCredential call does both verify the smsToken (that is part of that credential) AND then link it to an existing user. I can confirm that the linking works.

Comment: @bojeil  I have a question how i can do the above process having different VC for phone verification ad login.? any easy way.

Comment: What is "VC for phone verification ad"?

Answer (score 0):

For future comers and javascript users here is a way to achieve that:

```
const phoneCreds = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(this.windowRef.confirmationResult.verificationId, phoneConfirmCode);

        firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(phoneCreds)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('*********', response);
                // Manage other firestore data
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error', error);
            });
```